# App icon not displayed on MAC osX 10.5 for my app

Tags: macos, macros

I have created  .icns using .iconset for my Mac app,containing all sizes of icon recommended by apple. But still I cannot see my app icon when I install and launch my app on Mac osX 10.5

Comment: Show your code and provide more details to get better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Apple's current guidelines and using their latest toolset will give you icons that only work in newer versions of OS X. To get a set of icons that includes larger (@2x retina) resolutions and 10.5 compatible image formats, you need to use [Uli Kusterer's oldiconutil](https://github.com/uliwitness/oldiconutil).

Also, please see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772346/retina-ready-icns-icon-file-on-10-5-leopard-size-limit)--sometimes icon file sizes can be too large for 10.5, and require extra image compression.